# Where I'm wrong in this SQL statement?

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g

I'm developing a simple login form with JSF, Jboss and Oracle. The problem is that I have a problem when I make this SQL statement:

```
SQL_Statement = "SELECT Passwd from USERS WHERE Username = ?";

PreparedStatement passwordQuery = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_Statement);
passwordQuery.setString(1, userToCheck);

ResultSet result = passwordQuery.executeQuery();
if(result.next()){
    storedPassword = result.getString("Passwd");
```

This is the table structure in oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE "USERS"(
      "UserId" Integer NOT NULL,
      "GroupId" Integer,
      "SpecialNumber" Varchar2(60 ),
      "Username" Varchar2(50 ),
      "Passwd" Varchar2(50 ),
      "DateToChangePasswd" Date,
      "Address" Varchar2(60 ),
      "StateRegion" Varchar2(50 ),
      "Country" Varchar2(50 ),
      "AdminStatus" Varchar2(30 ),
      "Telephone" Varchar2(50 ),
      "DateUserAdded" Date,
      "UserExpireDate" Date,
      "DateUserLocked" Char(20 ),
      "City" Varchar2(50 ),
      "EMail" Varchar2(50 ),
      "Comment" Clob
    )
```

Maybe the SQL statement is not valid? Can you point me where is the problem?

Comment: The error message is "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "PASSWD": invalid identifier "

Comment: @Peter: it would be better if you update your question with the error message. it makes it easier to get the complete picture without having to read the comments...

Comment: Yeah, the lucidity of saying 'The problem is that I have a problem when I do this' is just mind-blowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this problem is caused by the double quotes used to declare the columns in the table. Enclosing the column names in double quotes make them case-sensitive. And your select query automatically transforms Passwd into PASSWD. So the column can't be found.

Change your create table query to

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
  UserId Integer NOT NULL,
  GroupId Integer,
  ...
```

This way, column names will be case insensitive.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm for more information.

Comment: It works, but the explanation is incorrect. True, quoted identifiers are case-sensitive, but that was not the problem, because they were used in the correct case. The problem is that the table was created with quoted identifiers, but the select statement was using unquoted identifiers. So the problem was the lack of quotes in the select statement, (or the presence of quotes in the create table statement, whichever way you want to see it,) and not the case sensitivity of identifiers.

Comment: Yes, that's what my answer says: "your select query automatically transforms Passwd into PASSWD"

Answer (score 2):

Quoted identifier is used so you have to use doubles with field name. For more info take a look at [google book page.](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=7piOCAFhnjsC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=quoted%20identifier%20delimiter%20in%20oracle&source=bl&ots=JjIkLhHKTi&sig=MyUzsSvgiBlaMV8oqG_bJRUUSq8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rWb4TvvUFYj4rQee4PH-Dw&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=quoted%20identifier%20delimiter%20in%20oracle&f=false)

Try this,

```
SQL_Statement = "SELECT \"Passwd\" from USERS WHERE \"Username\" = ?";
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I suppose they found your google book page link completely useless. Your answer is correct, but it would be nice if you explained why, and this link doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The source of your problem is that you defined your column names in quotes
("Passwd").

If you can't change your table (define the columns names without quotes), your query should be:

```
"SELECT \"Passwd\" from USERS WHERE Username = ?"
```

Comment: In fact, it should be "SELECT \"Passwd\" from USERS WHERE \"Username\" = ?"

Answer (score 1):

On this page: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm you can read the following:

> A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks (").
>   If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must
>   use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.

Therefore, your query should be as follows:

```
SQL_Statement = "SELECT \"Passwd\" from USERS WHERE \"Username\" = ?";
```